# How did Nixon not create the future Senator Chris Travers came from?

Tags: futurama

SPOILERS!

Can anyone explain how to resolve the paradox caused in this season's episode "Decision 3012?"

> How did Senator Chris Xaxar Travers winning the election cause him to cease to exist, thus allowing the crooked and reprehensible Head-in-Jar Nixon to win the election anyway.
>  The premise of the show stated Travers came to the past with Earth's last suit to prevent Nixon from winning? He did that, but then he disappears, allowing Nixon to win... What happened?

Comment: I'm unclear of what you are asking. Are you asking if there a way that the Senator can win without causing a paradox, or are you asking for an explanation as to why winning causes the paradox.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/19301/3383

Comment: It's hard to figure out what to spoiler and what not to spoiler for this one. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Senator Travers...

> used the [machine language time code](http://theinfosphere.org/Machine_language_time_code) to summon a [time sphere](http://theinfosphere.org/Time_sphere) and travel back in time, thus making him a [time paradox duplicate](http://theinfosphere.org/Time_paradox_duplicate), which we know from [*Bender's Big Score*](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender%27s_Big_Score) causes him to be filled with doom radiation which will eventually destroy him, correcting any paradoxes. The specific form of his doom seems to be simple disappearance, whereas other characters simply met more violent doomy ends.

This therefore ensures there is no paradox by allowing the future events to proceed in the same way as before.

Comment: By coming back in time, he basically cannot change the events of that future, he just relieved the people from that future of their final suit and one more mouth to feed...

Answer (score 0):

Senator Travers used the time code to go back in time to become president because Nixon sent the world into destruction. When Travers became president Nixon was never reelected, so the world was spared from Nixon. However, that meant that Travers would never go back in time to prevent Nixon from being reelected and becoming president himself. It was a paradox, and instead of making the world explode he just disappeared.